# Vue : Uncaught TypeError: _ctx.toPage is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

when I clicked the button:
it shows Uncaught TypeError: _ctx.toPage is not a function
how can I fix this bug?
please help me
[error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5ghs.jpg)

```
   <li v-for="pageLi of pageLis" :key="pageLi.id">
      <c-button @click="toPage(pageLi.path)">{{ pageLi.name }}</c-button>
    </li>


export default {
    setup() {
      const router = useRouter();
      const toPage = (path: string) => router.push(path);
      return {
        toPage,
      };
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The expected way to deal with **Event Handling** is to register an event handler with an **inline handler** or **method handler** (via the component `methods` property). See [Event Handling](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html) for more details.

However, even in what you're trying to do in this example, you should notice that the DOM is not available until the `mounted` state in the **Vue Lifecyle**. See [Lifecyle Hooks](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html) for more details.

Finally, from this code sample, it looks like you're trying to do either [Dynamic Route Matching](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html) or [Programmatic Navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html)? If so, the Vue Router documentation is your friend.